# How do I calculate sum of sum of two integer arrays such that common elements are counted once?

Tags: arithmetic, additive-combinatorics

Is there a constant time mathematical approach to calculate the sum of sum of two integer arrays such that the common numbers are counted only once?

For example, 
Sum of A1= {2,3} = 5 and

Sum of A2= {2,4} = 6

Can I have a mathematical equation to calculate the sum to be of 2+3+4 instead of counting 2 twice as 2+2+3+4?

Note: An efficient solution to the above problem would help solve the overall problem of finding pairwise intersections of a given list of subsets of an Universal set {1,2,3,4,....,n}

Comment: It won't be constant time - any approach will have to be at least $O(n)$ if the arrays  are $1$-dimensional and of length $n$

Comment: Is it a computational problem ? ... or do you have a mathematical description of the arrays ?

Comment: Also: are the arrays sorted beforehand? If they are pre-sorted then it makes the problem much easier ... although sorting doesn't take long, $O(n \log n)$

Comment: Yes, arrays can be sorted before hand.

Comment: @donald the problem here is - if I give you these two sums of arrays (you are allowed to do any preprocessing on these arrays) can we find the total sum of only the distinct elements . In constant time obviously.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to sum the union.

$$\sum_{x \in A \cup B} x$$

It can't be constant time as you need to check what are the elements.

Alternative approach:

$$\sum_{x\in A \cup B} x = \sum_{x\in A}x + \sum_{x \in B}x-\sum_{x \in A \cap B}x$$

Comment: I think your approach is not even a linear solution as the union operation will take logn for each element and so overall nlogn.

Comment: well, I didn't claim that they are linear right.

Comment: The next edit looks great. I was also following this path as yours. But then I got stuck in finding an efficient way to find the intersection. But again we need at least n iterations to find it.

Comment: what about using hash table?

Comment: Please elaborate a bit on how to use hash table to solve this problem.

Comment: I have also updated my problem description if that helps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642172/computing-set-intersection-in-linear-time  put one set into hash table, enumerate through the second set and check if it is in the hash table.